# Create 1bpp mask from image

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, drawing, gdi

How do you create a 1 bit per pixel mask from an image using GDI in C#?  The image I am trying to create the mask from is held in a System.Drawing.Graphics object.

I have seen examples that use Get/SetPixel in a loop, which are too slow. The method that interests me is one that uses only BitBlits, like [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Mask_Images/article.asp). I just can't get it to work in C#, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
   public static Bitmap BitmapTo1Bpp(Bitmap img) {
      int w = img.Width;
      int h = img.Height;
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
      BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
      for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        byte[] scan = new byte[(w + 7) / 8];
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
          Color c = img.GetPixel(x, y);
          if (c.GetBrightness() >= 0.5) scan[x / 8] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
        }
        Marshal.Copy(scan, 0, (IntPtr)((int)data.Scan0 + data.Stride * y), scan.Length);
      }
      bmp.UnlockBits(data);
      return bmp;
    }
```

GetPixel() is slow, you can speed it up with an unsafe byte*.

Comment: Thank you nobugz!  I have edited the original question as I was trying to avoid the Get/SetPixel loop.  My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

In the Win32 C API  the process to create a mono mask is simple.

- Create an uninitialzied 1bpp bitmap as big as the source bitmap.
- Select it into a DC.
- Select the source bitmap into a DC.
- SetBkColor on the destination DC to match the mask color of the source bitmap.
- BitBlt the source onto the destination using SRC_COPY.

For bonus points its then usually desirable to blit the mask back onto the source bitmap (using SRC_AND) to zero out the mask color there.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean LockBits? Bob Powell has an overview of LockBits [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx); this should provide access to the RGB values, to do what you need. You might also want to look at ColorMatrix, [like so](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/UseColorMatrixtograytheimage.htm).