# Write text to image with indexed pixel format

Tags: .net, image-processing, system.drawing, imaging

I have monochrome TIFF files (1 bpp) that I would like to write text to.  When I load them into System.Drawing.Image, and try to instantiate a Graphics object from that image, I receive the error, "A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format."

I can convert the images to a non-indexed format, such as JPEG, but then the resulting image size is very large.

I would like to accomplish this while keeping the image size down.  How can I write text onto these images without converting them to another format?

Comment: This isn't possible.  Write to a 16 or 24 or 32bpp bitmap, convert *that* to a 1bpp bitmap.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273624/c-gdi-create-1bpp-mask-from-image

Comment: It appears to be possible, in 3.5 at least, as per Jason's answer - using bitmap.Clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the idea in the comment left by Hans Passant, I located this article on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15186/Bitonal-TIFF-Image-Converter-for-NET

Adapting this code, I converted the image to 32bpp, wrote the text on that image, then converted it to 1bpp.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert images in memory using System.Drawing.Bitmap.Clone. This satisfies the small file size requirement. If you need a TIF on winforms, use TiffBitmapEncoder.

```
Bitmap bmpTif = new Bitmap(imagePath);

Bitmap bmp = bmpTif.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight),
    PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

// Do your g.DrawString's

Bitmap bmpNew = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight),
    PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
bmpNew.Save(imagePath2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an image manipulation API like [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) which supports TIFF images. I believe you can use the Annotate method to render text into it.

Hope this helps.