# how to draw text into picture using c#

Tags: c#

i tried to draw many texts into image but it get error i want to make user select in image with any path and save the result in the same path with another name this is my code

open dialoge button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog of1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    of1.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|PNG|*.png|GIF|*.gif|BMP|*.bmp";
    if ((of1.ShowDialog())==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
       imagepath = of1.FileName; //image path
    }
}
```

drawing button

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstText = "G";
    string secondText = "X";
    string thirdText = "H";
    string fourthText = "Z";
    string fifthText = "Y";
    string sixthText = "K";
    string seventhText = "F";
    string eighthText = "E";

    PointF GLocation = new PointF(60f, 15f);
    PointF XLocation = new PointF(145f, 15f);
    PointF HLocation = new PointF(200f, 15f);
    PointF ZLocation = new PointF(188f, 110f);
    PointF YLocation = new PointF(7f, 100f);
    PointF KLocation = new PointF(145f, 110f);
    PointF FLocation = new PointF(213f, 96f);
    PointF ELocation = new PointF(140f, 138f);

    string imageFilePath = imagepath;
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 10))
        {
            graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, GLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, XLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(thirdText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, HLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(fourthText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, ZLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(fifthText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, YLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(sixthText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, KLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(seventhText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, FLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(eighthText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, ELocation);
        }
    }
    bitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
}
```

error is

A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.

Comment: do a simple google search on the exact error `C# A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format` and it will have tons of examples of how to correct your issue.. good luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics on indexed image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313285/graphics-on-indexed-image)

Comment: @MethodMan if u can help me if not thanks :)

Comment: @MarkusEgle how the code will look like so ?

Comment: Do your own research, see the links in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10321128/3090544

Comment: i thing i solved the first problem but i have now another error 

 A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Answer (score 0):

Your original image has a palette and is not a 24/32bit RGB image. You cannot create a `Graphics` object for that since you cannot do all the things GDI+ can on it easily.

You can create a new `Bitmap` with 24/32bit RGB format, draw your existing image on that and then draw whatever you want on top of it and save.